# Doing a keep alive timer on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I am looking for a way to do a keep alive type javascript block when the mobile safari browser is in the background on the ipad.

i looked at the zombie tab hack, but this solution

[12 HTML5 tricks for mobile safari](http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/12-html5-tricks-mobile-81412803)

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
      <script>
        var mr = document.queryselector("meta"); setInterval(function() { mr.content=mr.content; }, 1000);
      </script>
```

Using the meta page refresh, the whole page refreshes...Not exactly what i am looking for.

What I am looking for is to run a javascript code block when the page/tab is sent to the background on the iPad.

Comment: In iOS 9, at least, some background script executions work on mobile safari displaying tabs (e.g., iPads, iPhone 6+ in landscape). See http://www.mobilexweb.com/samples/tab.html, and specifically http://www.mobilexweb.com/samples/tab1.html